# Iteration not Iterating?

Tags: python, iterator

I've been working a program for rolling dice.  One of the things I wanted to do was have it roll a specific number of dice (i.e. 2d6).  However, that part of the code does not seem to work,  I think it only returns a single roll of the die.

Here is what I have:

```
import random


# Format die rolls like so:  n dice d die size.  i.e. "4d6" will roll 4 six sided dice.
# You can also leave off the number of dice if you want to roll just one.

def die_roll(input_1):  # This is the dice rolling function
    roll = 0
    if "d" not in input_1:  # Should weed out most strings
        return "Not a valid die"
    splitter = input_1.split("d")  # should split the die roll into number of dice and die type
    die_type = splitter[1]  # Grabs the second item from the list created above and sets it to the type of die used
    pos1 = splitter[0]  # Tells you how many die to roll
    if pos1 == "":  # Puts a 1 in the multiplication place so that the math works in cases such as "d6" or "d4"
        pos1 = "1"
    if die_type not in ["4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "20", "100"]:  # Checks whether a valid die was indicated
        return "Not a valid die"
    else:
        if pos1 == "1":
            roll = dice(die_type)
            return roll
        else: # This specifically is what I need help with
            for i in range(int(pos1)):
                roll = roll + dice(die_type)
                return roll


def dice(roller):  # Rolls the actual dice.  Splitting it off here, theoretically, makes handling iteration.
    output = 0
    if roller == "4":
        output = random.randrange(1, 4)
    if roller == "6":
        output = random.randrange(1, 6)
    if roller == "8":
        output = random.randrange(1, 8)
    if roller == "10":
        output = random.randrange(1, 10)
    if roller == "12":
        output = random.randrange(1, 12)
    if roller == "20":
        output = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if roller == "100":
        output = random.randrange(1, 100)
    return output


while True:
    thing = input("What would you like to roll?")
    print(die_roll(thing))
```

So my question is, why does it not seem to iterate?

Comment: you return in your loop, so it exits the function at the end of the first step

Comment: `die_roll` should be further split into two functions: one that validates a dice input and returns a dice "object", and another that takes that object and focuses on using `dice` to obtain the desired total. (There's also on reason to handle one die and multiple dice separately. `for i in range(1)`:` would be a perfectly valid way to "iterate" over a single die.

Comment: (Also, note that grammatically, if you aren't going to use "dice" as both the singular and plural, then "die" is the singular and "dice" is the plural, not the other way around as you are currently using them. `def die(roller)` and `def dice_roll(dice):`.)

Comment: Your code should be using `random.randint` which includes both start and stop values in the possible values. `randrange` will generate exclude the last value. That is: calling `randrange(1,4` will yield values from [1,2,3] and never 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentiation of `return roll` is wrong. This causes the function to return after 1 iteration.

```
else: # This specifically is what I need help with
    for i in range(int(pos1)):
        roll = roll + dice(die_type)
    return roll
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle validating your input separately from actually trying to roll the dice.

```
def validate_dice_input(s: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    try:
        n_dice, n_sides = s.split("d")
        n_dice = int(n_dice)
        n_sides = int(n_sides)
    except Exception:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid dice input {s}")
    if n_dice < 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Cannot roll a negative number of dice ({n_dice})")

    if n_sides not in [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown die size '{n_sides}'")

    return n_dice, n_sides
```

Then, rolling a single die is really no different than rolling multiple dice. Roll *all* of them, and sum the total.

```
def dice_roll(dice: Tuple[int, int]) -> int:
    n, s = dice
    return sum(die_roll(s) for _ in range(n))
```

`die_roll` doesn't necessarily have to do its own validation. As long as you get an integer input, the work is the same whether the input corresponds to a "real" die size or not. (Having a `Die` class with a `roll` method would help prevent calling `roll` on invalid dice, as you can prevent an invalid instance of `Die` from being created in the first place.)

```
def die_roll(sides: int) -> int:
    return random.randint(1, sides)
```

Then your loop, once it gets a value from `validate_date_input`, can simply call `dice_roll` with the value.

```
while True:
    thing = input("What would you like to roll?")
    try:
        dice = validate_dice_input(thing)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(exc)
        print("Try again")
        continue

    print(dice_roll(dice))
```